# Error in Twitter connection

Tags: social-media

I write `ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]` and the answer is

> OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication::reqbdy: The service Twitter returned invalid request token response <<5980>>.

Comment: Could you make your question more explicit? What have you tried to troubleshoot the problem so far?

Comment: As per @MarcoB, you state a fact. What is your question? What have you tried so far? Have you checked that your internet connection is working and that you can connect to Twitter with your browser? Personnally, the above command is correctly asking me to sign-in to Twitter.

Comment: Solved. I have try several different contections to twitter in one day and the API reject from a number of connections. I have wait one day and all is working again. my experience is that if you make many test connections the api blocks you. I hope this help to others. Thanks to all